# bash system wide interactive non-login configuration

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

In ubuntu directory /etc/profile.d allows me to configure **bash** from my software package (I mean *.deb). But it doesn't work for interactive non-login shells. How to add something to that type of shells, which will be system wide?

Because I need it for **deb** package I cannot modify /etc/bash.bashrc (or can I somehow? )

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found workaround. I'm modifying /etc/bash.bashrc.

Just I'm wonder if bash will update, it will overwrite my changes?